# How to restore previous state of cell when navigating back to TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an audio player app that uses a navigation controller to segue between two TableViewControllers (AudioBookViewController & TopicViewController).

[image: Storyboard]
When a user selects a book, they are taken to all of the available topics they can play for that book:

[image: TopicViewController]

The problem I have is that the unwind segue from the navigation controller pops the TopicViewController when moving back to the AudioBookViewController. This means that I lose the state of any cell that was playing in the TopicViewController when navigating back to it. If a user plays a topic, they should see that that row is still playing when coming back to the topicViewController, instead, they all reset to a non-playing state.

I use the prepareForSegue function to reference both ViewControllers to each other and assign the currently playing cell to a chosenCell variable that I can pass to one another. I tried simply assigning this cell to the table row within the viewDidAppear function, and it works, but there is like a 0.5 second lag before the row updates to a playing state. I want the state to update before the view appears.

My next solution was to grab an indexPath from the chosen cell and change the state of that cell within the tableView cellForRowAt: function, but that code is looking convoluted and I've always heard that that function's contents should be simple and clean. I feel like this isn't the best way to achieve what I want.

What is the preferred method of restoring information to a cell in a tableview, when you've already navigated away from it and those cells are repopulated with new instances when revisiting its ViewController?

**Within TopicViewController:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: PlayableAudioCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PlayableAudioCell

    if let chapters = audioBook?["Chapters"] as? [AnyObject], let chapter = chapters[indexPath.row] as? AnyObject{

        cell.mainTopicLabel.text = chapter["Title"] as! String + "- "
        cell.subTopicLabel.text = chapter["Subtitle"] as? String
        cell.chapter = chapter
        cell.delegate = self

    }

    return cell
}
```

**Within PlayableAudioCell:**

```
class PlayableAudioCell: UITableViewCell {

   var delegate: PlayableAudioCellDelegate?
   var isPlaying: Bool = false
   var chapter: AnyObject?

   @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var mainTopicLabel: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var subTopicLabel: UILabel!

   @IBAction func play(_ sender: UIButton) {
       delegate?.play(cell: self)
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       // Initialization code
   }

   override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

       // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

}

protocol PlayableAudioCellDelegate{

    //var chapter: AnyObject? { get }
    func play(cell: PlayableAudioCell)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue with my original idea, of passing back the cell that was playing, and, depending on the state of the cell, update it to a playing state. works pretty well, but I imagine there is a better way of doing this and it doesn't seem very extensible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not fully understand what you mean. 
But from my perspective you should assign values of current audio states to controller. When tableView will reload you should assign those values to right cell.
I hope it helps.